# Positioning maths issue on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, math

I have a canvas with a square and a camera position set up in my code that allows me to scroll around and zoom in.

But my logic seems a bit off when trying to detect when the mouse is over the square in the position.

The square is positioned at 0,0 the white dot in the square represents it's position.

The detection for mouse works fine if the scale or camera position is unchanged, but once either one is altered my function which converts mouse position on element to world position causes problems.

My function looks like this:

```
function check(evt,el){
    var x = evt.offsetX;
    var y = evt.offsetY;
    output.innerHTML = 'Scale: '+scale;
    output.innerHTML += '<br/>Screen Space x: '+x+', y: '+y;

        x += camera.x;
        x -= element.width/2

        y += camera.y;
        y -= element.height/2;

    output.innerHTML += '<br/>Camera Position: '+camera.x+', y: '+camera.y;
    output.innerHTML += '<br/>World Space x: '+x+', y: '+y;
        var radius = 20 * scale;
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length;i++){
            if(x > obj[i].x-radius 
            && x < obj[i].x+radius 
            && y > obj[i].y-radius 
            && y < obj[i].y+radius){
                output.innerHTML += '<br/>In';
                return false;
            }
        }
    output.innerHTML += '<br/>out';
}
```

I have also managed to reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle here **http://jsfiddle.net/4n7LLasz/**.

**Reproducing the problem:**

Zoom in or out with mouse wheel, click and drag the square some where off center. Then move your mouse over the red square, it should say `in` when the mouse is over the square else it will say `out`.

But currently the accuracy of this check is incorrect, and I cannot figure out where I am going wrong with my maths for my `check` function (on line 17).

You can see the issue here too, notice the in/out at bottom of the image:

[image]

I hope some one can help spot my mistake so i can finally get this to work!

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be working correctly for me in Chrome 48 on a mac...used the trackpad to change scale, drug the square around, still says in and out when appropriate.

Comment: Are you making a game using javascript?

Comment: @JaredSmith http://i.imgur.com/N7ZPq75.gif nope - not working for me on latest Chrome. Doubt browser would matter with javascript math related issues. Or operating system.

Comment: Yeah, I apparently wasn't thorough enough, I'm getting the error now.

Comment: @JaredSmith fair enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition you are checking for in and out is little buggy. it doesn't match with original square translations and size of radius. so change `radius = 10 * scale` because your square size is 20*20 so radius will be 10 and in first two line of checking in if condition, change to this `x > obj[i].x-10 && x < obj[i].x+radius+50` this will fix issue.

Let me explain it,

1. First move your mouse until status changes to `out` to `in`.
2. You will find that its too early `in` some cases and in some you are still inside that red square and it shows `out`.
3. Just trace the `in` and `out`.
4. You will find the invisible **SQUARE** that is created by your `if logic`
5. Just measure dimensions of that square you will find that it too big and is little left side then original red square.

So what i did is make some changes so that it matches original square.

I changed radius = 20 * scale to 10 * scale because that invisible square is too big about twice the size in comparison to real one.

Last change was about that translation that your did when you first created **RED Square**. `x > obj[i].x-10` this translates imaginary square to little right and added 50 to `obj[i].x+radius+50` to maintain original size of square that i changed by putting -10 instead of scale.

Comment: Thank you for explaining :)